# TFS 2008 server time

Tags: .net, tfs

Is there a way getting the TFS server time, I didn't find any method in the API which give such functionality.

I have try many ways but failed to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI to get the time from the server. I'm not sure what additional privileges you would need.

In PowerShell:

```
Get-WMIObject -ComputerName TfsServer -Class Win32_LocaTtime
```

This is, of course, something that will work for any Windows system.

Comment: .NET fully supports WMI (via types in `System.Management`), PSH is just quicker to use for a one off. There will only be one instance of `Win32_LocalTime`, so WMI query is `SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime`.

Comment: There is no way to that in a clean way ?
for example using tfs web services...
or any other way using tfs API...

Comment: @user266203: Not as far as I know (and I would expect to find nothing for this). You could work through the VS SDK to look at the TFS client library.